# Keys of a Particular Scale Only in GarageBand on OS X

Tags: audio, garageband

I used to have an iPad and had great time using GarageBand.

The feature that made my time fun is mostly "Scale" i.e. when I choose a particular scale, for instance "D#maj Pentatonic Blues", the instrument suddenly turns into a "virtual" instrument which does not allow you to play a note that is outside of the scale.

It's not that I don't have any knowledge about the music, but that was super fun. You can mess around all you want and you never get a bad note.

Why is this not available in OSX? Isn't this a great feature?

If it is available, where can I find it?

Edit: A keyboard looks like this when you use scale: [image: this]

Edit 2: I forgot to mention. I have a MacBook Pro right now. That is the reason I ask this question.

Comment: GarageBand is available for $4.99 in the Apple App Store.

Comment: i have the app.